# Next badge search input is too tall

Tags: bug, design, localization, badge-progress

On some localized SO sites (like ruSO, esSO, ptSO) the height of badge search input is too large due to wrapping the filter buttons on the left:

> [image: ruSO]

> [image: esSO]

> [image: ptSO]

Could this please be fixed somehow?

Tested on iPad Pro 11", iPadOS 16.2, Google Chrome

Not reproducible on PC mode for esSO at least:

> [image: esSO PC mode]

Comment: Is it "too tall such that it doesn't work or causes disruption" or "taller than I'd like to see it, but is fully functional"?

Comment: Side note: I couldn't find any other stacks that are affected. Not a side note: [rewording will help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD4TU.png); a broader solution would be [increasing popup width by 10% to 660px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKJF8.png) on localized sites. Completely side note: I actually doubt anyone would fix this, although it looks borked it's site specific

Comment: Is this really an issue *just* on localized SO sites, or is it what happens on *any* site where the screen width/window width/viewport width makes it such that the filter buttons wrap? In other words, is this *actually* specifically related to the localized SO sites, or really that it just happens on those for you with the viewport width which you're using? You should be able to test that by changing your window/viewport width on both sites you're seeing the issue on and ones you're not seeing the issue on.

Comment: @Makyen [tag:design] here means that the issue is mainly with layout. It still can be used, but looks ugly.

Comment: @mak it's exactly specifically related to ru.SO and no other site at this time, and it doesn't depend on scaling since this very popup window has 600px of fixed real estate

Comment: @nicael ruSO, ptSO, esSO, rusSE

Comment: @αλεχολυτ have you checked them though? I couldn't confirm the same issue anywhere else

Comment: @nicael rewording is bad practice for good localization

Comment: @nicael of course I've checked, you can do it by self, just register.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ it's actually ru.SO and rus.SE, no other language among listed has got so long wordings that they would wrap

Comment: @nicael see updates

Comment: weird, somehow can't repro that

Comment: I, also, only see it only on  ru.SO and rus.SE. Are you sure your browser is set to view with 100% scaling?

Comment: @Makyen I'm not sure that scaling (in terms of webpage) for touch screen devices is really necessary, since scale can be changed easily by pinching.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I have yet to see any issue report on SE where the cause was the user using a scaling other than 100% didn't result in it being closed. I'm not saying that's good, just that's one of the effective limits on issue reports. Given that you're seeing something that two other people are not seeing, it would be good to know more information about what you're using to display it, so it could be duplicated, including any scaling, the browser you're using, OS, etc.

Comment: @Makyen browser and OS already reported here